# Remove category description on product page Magento

Tags: magento, categories

I'm using magento `1.9.0.1` with `RWD` theme.

The category description is showed into single product page (on Top). I would like to hide it, can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

find file

```
/magento/app/design/frontend/default/{your_theme}/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

and remove this code:

```
<p class="cat-desc">'.$category->getDescription().'</p>
```

In my case, it's 163 line. Here is the final code:

```
echo '<a class="categlinks" href="'.$category->getURL().'" style="color:#383838"></span> '.$category->getName().'</a><p class="cat-desc-under"><a  href="'.$category->getURL().'"><!--Shop--> '.$category->getName().' Products >></a></p> ';
```